# Expressing a length in a triangle with no angles given

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let there be $ABC$ an isosceles triangle $(AB = AC)$. $D $ is a point on $AB$ such that $AD  = 2BD$. $E$ a point on $BC$ such that $2EC = BE$ . Express $DE$  in terms of the base, $a$, and the sides, $b$.

Thing is there is no angles here, so the Law of cosines cannot be applied...

Comment: "the base $A$ and the sides $B$"? $A$ and $B$ are vertices, right? How can a vertex be a base, or a single vertex be "sides"? Do you mean the lengths of the sides opposite to these vertices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a picture. As usual, let $a$ be the length of the side opposite $A$. and let $b=c$ be the lengths of the other two sides.

We **can** use the Cosine Law. Note that
$$b^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\angle B)$$
and therefore $\cos(\angle B)=a/2b$.
Also,
$$(DE)^2=(b/3)^2 +(2a/3)^2 -2(b/3)(2a/3)\cos(\angle B).$$
But we know $\cos(\angle B)$. Substitute and simplify.

**Remark:** The first use of the Cosine Law was unnecessary. Drop a perpendicular from $A$ to $BC$. We can read off that $\cos(\angle B)=(a/2)/b$.

Comment: hi, many thanks for your help, that's a pretty efficient way of dealing with this problem...for the sake of comparison, did you also get:  $\frac{1}{3}\sqrt {a^2+2b^2} $ ?

Comment: I get $\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{b^2+2a^2}$.

Comment: so did I, thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. But in your earlier comment $a$ and $b$ were interchanged.

Comment: Yeah I know, I simply chose the constants the other way around..

Comment: There is a standard convention that the length of the side opposite the vertex called $A$ is by default called $a$, and so on for other letters.

Comment: I'll try to keep that in mind..Many thanks Mate!